# positioning issue with divs centering

Tags: html, css

I want to have some div boxes centered, yet nothing I tried worked. Because it's quite a bit of code, I will be posting the link to the website its on:

http://www.klodel.com/test.html

The target is, to have the colored boxes centered in the middle of the grey box.

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

does work on the FULL grey box, yet not on the "skillbox" which is the container around the four colored ones.

here the code:
html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="pagebox">
    <div class="skillbox">
        <div class="flatbox flatbox-me">
            <div class="flatbox-image">
                <img style="width:64px; height:64px;" src="placeholder.png">
            </div>
            <div class="flatbox-title">
                <p>Ich mit mir</p>
             </div>
        </div>

        <div class="flatbox flatbox-you">
            <div class="flatbox-image">
                <img style="width:64px; height:64px;" src="placeholder.png">
            </div>
            <div class="flatbox-title">
                <p>Ich mit dir</p>
             </div>
        </div>

        <div class="flatbox flatbox-team">
            <div class="flatbox-image">
                <img style="width:64px; height:64px;" src="placeholder.png">
            </div>
            <div class="flatbox-title">
                <p>Ich im Team</p>
             </div>

        </div>

        <div class="flatbox flatbox-leadership">
            <div class="flatbox-image">
                <img style="width:64px; height:64px;" src="placeholder.png">
            </div>
            <div class="flatbox-title">
                <p>Leadership</p>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.pagebox
{
  width:900px;
  height:800px;
  background-color:#bdc3c7;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

.skillbox
{
  width:900px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

.flatbox 
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float:left;
  top:30px;
}

.flatbox p
{
  color: #fff;
}

.flatbox-image
{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 18px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 64px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flatbox-title
{  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.flatbox-me
{  
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.flatbox-you
{  
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left:8px;
}

.flatbox-team
{  
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #3498db;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left:8px;
}

.flatbox-leadership
{  
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #e67e22;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left:8px;
}
```

Comment: You should work on narrowing the code/problem down as links to sites without code in the question are off-topic here. Plus, that usually helps troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: there i added the code, just the stuff related to the issue ofc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Centered in what way? Horizontally? Vertically? Both? Here's an easy way to center them horizontally:

```
.skillbox {text-align: center;}

.flatbox {display: inline-block; float: none;}
```

(Of course, the `float: none` is just to override the float you have. Just take them both out.)

Comment: ah... thank you, yea that makes sense. im still a little new to the "display" thing. Thank you a lot.